# I want to know how to execute java(servlet) class before execute jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web

I want to know how to execute java(servlet) class before execute jsp. supose i hava index.jsp(welcome page) and index.java(servlet page). i run the project,now cotroll goes to execute index.java(servlet) instead of index.jsp.After executing index.java(servlet) controll come back to index.jsp and execution continue...

in C# .aspx.cs page execute before .aspx page by using codeBehind concept similar i want achive in java

Comment: question is not clear, do you need load any .java before loading index.jsp?

Comment: ok,after loading java(servlet) control come back to jsp file

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. JSPs are also Servlets, quoted from  [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_architecture.htm) :

> The JSP engine loads the JSP page from disk and converts it into a
>   servlet content. This conversion is very simple in which all template
>   text is converted to println( ) statements and all JSP elements are
>   converted to Java code. This code implements the corresponding dynamic
>   behavior of the page.

What do you want to do ?